OpenImages through FiftyOne - load only drawings
I am trying to use OpenImages V7 dataset through FiftyOne python interface. My goal is to get a dataset of images classified as drawings or paintings (goal is to recognize a photo from drawing).
On OpenImages web page I see that "Painting" and "Drawing" classes are there, I can filter by them. But when trying to get the images by FiftyOne, I am getting notice "Ignoring invalid classes ['Painting', 'Drawing']", and acquired images are centainly not drawings. If I run recommended fo.utils.openimages.get_classes(version='v7') , the list does not include "Painting" or "Drawing", even though the web page recognizes it.
I am using following code to load the dataset (only 100 images for testing purposes):
import fiftyone as fo
import fiftyone.zoo as foz

dataset = foz.load_zoo_dataset(
    "open-images-v7",
    split="validation",
    label_types=["classifications"],
    classes=["Painting", "Drawing"],
    max_samples=100,
)

cls = fo.utils.openimages.get_classes(version='v7')
print(cls)

session = fo.launch_app(dataset)

session.wait()

Do I understand something wrong? Why web interface ( https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/visualizer/index.html ) recognizes "Drawing" and "Painting" classes, but python interface does not?
